# Vector as Parameter C

Tags: c, pointers, vector

I have to do the following:

Given a vector with random numbers, separate it in 2 other vectors, odd and even. But in the function, all vectors must be passed via parameter (can't use global).
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void vetores(int *vetor, int *A, int *B)
{
    int i = 0,aux;
    for(i = 0;i < 100; i++)
    {
        if(vetor[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            aux = vetor[i];
            A[i] = aux;
        }else{
            aux = vetor[i];
            B[i] = aux;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int vetor[101], a[51], b[51],i;

    /*a = (int)malloc(sizeof(int)*51);
    b = (int)malloc(sizeof(int)*51);*/

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        vetor[i] = i;
    }

    vetores(vetor,a,b);

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        if(vetor[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("%d",a[i]);
        }else
        {
            printf("%d",b[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you test that code, the vector is being altered (it is not supposed to) and the A vector is not receiving the even numbers!

Comment: You're passing your arguments as pointers and your function returns `void`.  What, exactly, did you *think* would happen?

Comment: In `vectores` why are you storing the values in `A` and `B` at position `i`?

Comment: You need to have seperate counts for each array A and B.

Comment: @JackManey, I might be missing something, but what is the problem?

Comment: @JackManey: There is no such thing as "pass by reference" in C.  The OP is passing pointers by value.  That may come off as pedantic, but there is a difference, and using incorrect terminology will only serve to confuse beginners.

Comment: @EdS. - A fair point.  Thankfully, I was able to edit my comment above.

Comment: Also, once you've got it working correctly, if the values in vetor are truly random, allowing only 51 elements for the "even" and "odd" arrays is asking for trouble. (Which, by the way, is exactly the same trouble you run into now, but for a different reason.)

Comment: @JackManey You did mean that `int* vetor` should have been `const int* vetor` in the function, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're indexing your *outputs* based on the position in the *input*.

For example, if your first even number is at `input[3]`, then you're writing it to `even_output[3]`, where is should (probably) be at `even_output[0]`.

You probably want something like:

```
if (input[i] %2 == 0)
    *A++ = input[i];
else
    *B++ = input[i];
```

You probably also need to do something to tell the caller how many odd and even numbers you found (and the caller may have to allocate memory a bit differently unless those counts are equal -- right now, you have 101 inputs, and 51 spots allocated for each output. If you had (for example) 60 even and 40 odd numbers, you'll write beyond end of the space you've allocated for the even numbers. With the inputs you've provided, that problem won't arise, but in almsot any other case, it's not only possible, but in fact likely.

Answer (score 1):

You need separate index count for array A and B.

Try this:

```
void vetores(int *vetor, int *A, int *B)
{
    int i = 0,aux;
    int aIndex = 0, bIndex = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < 100; i++)
    {
        if(vetor[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            A[aIndex] = vetor[i];
            aIndex++;
        }else{
            B[bIndex] = vetor[i];
            bIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Try using a nice [debugger tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger), that will help you find this kind of errors in the code.

You also need to check the length of your arrays:

```
int vetor[101], a[51], b[51]
```

I think `a` or `b` could have more than 51 values if they are random.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints: Beside you nearly always misspelled "vector", you are using classic c arrays not vectors. Your vectors method needs some heavy refactoring as you are unnecessary using extra memory and double assign variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void vectores(int *vector, int *A, int *B)
{
    int i = 0, k = 0, l = 0;
    for(;i < 100; i++)
    {
        if(vector[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            A[k++] = vector[i];
        }else{
            B[l++] = vector[i];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int vector[100], a[51], b[51],i;

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = i;
    }

    vectores(vector,a,b);
    for(i = 0; i < 51; i++){
        printf("%d          %d",a[i], b[i] );
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is technically not an answer to your question, but if you want to separate the odd and even values, you're better off doing a single pass of QuickSort on the last bit of each value, e.g.

```
int temp, i = 0, j = N-1;
while ( i < j ) {
    while ( vetor[i] & 1 == 0 )
        i += 1;
    while ( vetor[j] & 1 == 1 )
        j -= 1;
    if ( i < j ) {
        temp = vetor[i];
        vetor[i] = vetor[j];
        vetor[j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

The above is untested, if you find any bugs, feel free to keep them.